# Apache Tiles : change template page at runtime

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I have a question : suppose that in a spring MVC 3.0 enviroment i manage Views with Tiles : I have a xml file with definitions of all views. Every view extends a specific template. I have two templates : one for rendering a completeDOM () and one for partialDOM (.....).The problem is, there are some views that can be retrieved in fullDOM and also in partialDOM, but i don't want to write two similars definitions.

I was thinking to a dynamic approach : inject the template of a view at runtime, specifying an http parameter which should contains the name of the template. If the request contains the parameter, than Tiles should override the template exteded by the view, with the template detected by http parameter value.

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring tilesConfigurer you need to set mutable container:

```
<property name="useMutableTilesContainer" value="true"/>
<property name="checkRefresh" value="true"/>
```

And in your Spring Controller:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
MutableTilesContainer container = (MutableTilesContainer)ServletUtil.getContainer(request.getSession().getServletContext());
Attribute attribute = new Attribute("your template jsp");
HashMap<String, Attribute>  attributes = new HashMap<String, Attribute>();
attributes.put("body", attribute);
Definition definition = new Definition("your definition name", "your jsp", attributes);
definition.setExtends("your definition template name");
definition = PatternUtil.replacePlaceholders(definition, "your definition name", new Object());
container.register(definition, request, response);
model.setViewName("your definition name");
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I had needed to do this very thing so I thought I'd share my solution.

Tiles allows what they refer to as "[runtime composition](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/runtime.html)", which lets you modify definitions. So you can reuse an existing definition and just swap the template:

```
<tiles:insertDefinition name="existingDefinition" template="alternateTemplate.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a view preparer might help:
http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/preparer.html